# Tetris piece construction using C# array

Tags: c#, arrays

I've looked for a question like the one I'm about to ask, but haven't found what I'm looking for.
**Question:**
How can I implement tetris pieces with C# arrays?

I have only a basic understanding of arrays, I have the concept of initialization, but past that I'm a little lost on how to actually construct it. For example:

```
public static (type)[,] Matrix = new (type)[x,y];
```

I would guess that the thing I'm missing is how to assign the values of the pieces. Past the initialization, I know I can change the x and y values(in this case) but how do I put the individual blocks into those pseudo coordinates? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Matrix[0,0] = someBlock; Matrix[0,1] = someBlock` do you mean this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Like, let's say the 'Matrix' is 4x4. How do I place a block into each of the points that I need to create a shape?

Comment: in other words, and if I was using something like Unity to do this: `public static Transform[,] Matrix = new Transform[4,4];` would I have to put in pseudo: `Matrix[x,y] = block_one; Matrix[x,y] = block_two; etc...` very similar to your comment @Roma. Or, is there a more simple way for getting all the blocks into their correct places? You know, not one by one for each of the piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays support initializers just fine:

```
int[,] Matrix = new int[3,3]{ { 0, 0, 1 },
                              { 0, 0, 1 },
                              { 0, 1, 1 } };
```